# Error while importing a sbt multiproject into intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I came across a necessity to re-organize code on which I have been working for some time into a sbt multiproject. I have consulted two sources as examples:

1. A sbt 1.* example (used as base) by Pol Bassiner: [sbt 1.* multiproject example](https://github.com/pbassiner/sbt-multi-project-example/blob/master/build.sbt)
2. A sbt < 1.* example (mostly for .scala files in /project) by Aaron Pritzlaff:[sbt < 1.* multiproject example](https://github.com/aaronp/multi-project)

Based on the two above here is the current structure of my project:

```
    [vgorcinschi@localhost Learning Concurrent Programming Test]$ tree -L 2
.
├── build.sbt
├── chapter01_introduction
│   ├── build.sbt
│   └── src
├── chapter02_concurrency_on_jvm
│   ├── build.sbt
│   └── src
├── chapter03_traditional_concurrency
│   ├── build.sbt
│   └── src
└── project
    ├── build.properties
    ├── Common.scala
    ├── Dependencies.scala
    └── target

8 directories, 7 files
```

I will eagerly post details of the rest of configuration files as you will advise, but for now most pertinent to the error seems to be the root `build.sbt`. Here is its content:

```
name := "learning concurrent programming in scala"
organization in ThisBuild := "ca.vgorcinschi"
scalaVersion in ThisBuild := "2.12.6"

import Dependencies._
import Common

version := "0.0.1"

resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"

lazy val chapter01_introduction = project.
    settings(Common.settings: _*).
    settings(libraryDependencies ++= Dependencies.akkaDependencies)

lazy val chapter02_concurrency_on_jvm = project.
    dependsOn(chapter01_introduction).
    settings(Common.settings: _*, 
    mainClass in Compile := Some("org.learningconcurrency.concurrency_on_jvm.PriorityTaskPool_Ex8")).
    settings(libraryDependencies ++= Dependencies.commonDependencies)

lazy val chapter03_traditional_concurrency = project.
    dependsOn(chapter01_introduction).
    settings(Common.settings: _*).
    settings(libraryDependencies ++= Dependencies.commonDependencies)

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
    aggregate(chapter01_introduction, chapter02_concurrency_on_jvm, chapter03_traditional_concurrency)
```

When I import it into my Intellij IDEA (2017.3, having both Scala and SBT plugins) I get this error: `build.sbt]:8: '.' expected but ';' found.`

For interest's sake this is the entire stack trace:

```
Error while importing sbt project:

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=2048M; support was removed in 8.0
[info] Loading settings from idea.sbt ...
[info] Loading global plugins from /home/vgorcinschi/.sbt/1.0/plugins
[info] Updating ProjectRef(uri("file:/home/vgorcinschi/.sbt/1.0/plugins/"), "global-plugins")...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Loading project definition from /home/vgorcinschi/ideaProjects/Learning Concurrent Programming Test/project
[info] Updating ProjectRef(uri("file:/home/vgorcinschi/ideaProjects/Learning%20Concurrent%20Programming%20Test/project/"), "learning-concurrent-programming-test-build")...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 2 Scala sources to /home/vgorcinschi/ideaProjects/Learning Concurrent Programming Test/project/target/scala-2.12/sbt-1.0/classes ...
[info] Done compiling.
[error] [/home/vgorcinschi/ideaProjects/Learning Concurrent Programming Test/build.sbt]:8: '.' expected but ';' found.
Invalid response.
```

I would appreciate any help or advise as I am hesitant to say whether the issue is on intellij or sbt side.

Answer (score 0):

I have found what the issue was (well issue**s**):

1. Despite the error message, the real culprit was `import Common` two lines above. Removing it took care of that error.
2. Then I had another complaining of the syntax used for appending to common settings in a sub-project:

   settings(Common.settings: _*, 
       mainClass in Compile := Some("org.learningconcurrency.concurrency_on_jvm.PriorityTaskPool_Ex8"))

I will have to figure it out how to do it the right way. So far removing it helped me importing the project without errors.

Finally this is the working root build.sbt that works for me:

```
name := "learning concurrent programming in scala"
organization in ThisBuild := "ca.vgorcinschi"
scalaVersion in ThisBuild := "2.12.6"

version := "0.0.1"

resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"

lazy val chapter01_introduction = project.
    settings(Common.settings: _*).
    settings(libraryDependencies ++= Dependencies.akkaDependencies)

lazy val chapter02_concurrency_on_jvm = project.
    dependsOn(chapter01_introduction).
    settings(Common.settings: _*).
    settings(libraryDependencies ++= Dependencies.commonDependencies)

lazy val chapter03_traditional_concurrency = project.
    dependsOn(chapter01_introduction).
    settings(Common.settings: _*).
    settings(libraryDependencies ++= Dependencies.commonDependencies)

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
    aggregate(chapter01_introduction, chapter02_concurrency_on_jvm, chapter03_traditional_concurrency)
```